# how to make 2d array from (1, 20) + inhomogeneous array

Tags: python, arrays, list, 2d

I have an array that is output of a network in this shape:
`a=[[array ([...]),array ([....])], .....]` arrays are inhomogeneous. How Can I change it to a 2d array?

```
max_length = max(len(arr) for arr in list_of_arrays)

padded_arrays = [np.pad(arr, (0, max_length - len(arr)), 'constant') for arr in list_of_arrays]

two_d_array = np.vstack(padded_arrays)

column_to_insert = np.array(['np.array'] * len(list_of_arrays)).reshape(-1, 1)
two_d_array_with_column = np.insert(two_d_array, 0, column_to_insert, axis=1)
```